# why would same query use index_merge with intersection for some data and index_subquery for other

Tags: mysql

The query is filtering for all manufacturers [for given client] that have products in a specific location.

This query took .16 seconds for 96 rows

```
SELECT manufac_id
  FROM manufac
 WHERE client_id = 4
   AND manufac_id IN
    (
       SELECT DISTINCT manufac_id
         FROM product
        WHERE client_ID = 4 
          AND location_ID = 11
    )
```

and this took 2.3 seconds for 50 rows

```
SELECT manufac_id
  FROM manufac
 WHERE client_id = 7
   AND manufac_id IN
    (
       SELECT DISTINCT manufac_id
         FROM product
        WHERE client_ID = 7
          AND location_ID = 23
    )
```

So 2nd one is taking about 10 times longer for 1/2 the data !?!?!?

The client with the faster query actually has more data (lots more), and when I use EXPLAIN, the 1st query shows normal index_subquery but the 2nd shows index_merge using intersect.

I can't figure out why this one client's data is so slow with this query.

I'm not looking for ways to modify or optimize the query, just want to know what might cause this.

Comment: You could join those data instead of using IN it will for sure use a better plan.

Comment: How many rows in `product` table are with client_ID 7? What are the indexes? What happens if you add index hint (`USE INDEX(client_ID_index)` or smth) into inner query?

Comment: I ran the same queries on a copy of the database made a few months ago; the data is not very different, and both clients execute normally.

The query for client 7 on production db shows index_merge using intersect, but on the dev db copy it has normal index_subquery.

Maybe an index is corrupt, or isn't being updated, or needs to be rebuilt?